# defining vs. non-defining relative elements

Tags: non-restrictive

I know the internet fundamentals of subject but the following sentence has me confused.

> Additionally, guidelines are prepared that **will guide the user
>   through the phases of the automation project.**

Is the bold part defining or non-defining? I assumed it is defining as, in order to understand the sentence as it is intended by the writer, the type of guidelines have to be specified. For me, non-defining so far really only contained information non-necessary for the reader, such as in the following sentence where the information I intend to convey is that I also read a book about music, with the additional information that did like it:

> I also read a book about music, which I happened to, at the same time, like.

I thought that when I want to convey the idea that I like the book in particular, then this would make the information and thus the relative clause defining.

However, I am now unsure, as a sentence with a defining relative clause like

> He held out the finger that was broken

really does not make any sense if the specific finger was not mentioned earlier in the text. Yet, the same could be said about the guidelines, at least somehow. Is the difference here that **the finger** uses a definite article? Or was I correct with my thinking in the first place.

Comment: Supplementary (non-defining) _that_ relatives are not permitted, so your examples with "that" can only be integrated (defining) relatives. _Wh_ relatives can be either integrated or supplementary. Your "book" example looks like a supplementary one, since you probably like more than just one book about music.